# Unknown stored procedure being called during update query

Tags: sql-update, sql-server-2012

I've got SQL Server 2012 with a table having a field layout like this:

```
 (UID bigint, Email varchar(64), Password varchar(64))
```

When I run a query like this:

```
   Update *tablename*
   Set [Password]="some_new_value"
   Where [UID]=1;
```

I get this error"

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UserModify, Line 16 Invalid
>   object name 'updated'.

Normally, I'd have no problems fixing this, but I'm not calling a stored procedure, and there's no stored procedure in my database called UserModify. So I'm at a complete loss as to what's going on here. Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: What is `*tablename*` is this an actual name of your table? If no then please show your actual query.

Comment: Check whether any update triggers are defined on your *tablename*

Comment: Did you check for triggers on the table?

Comment: *tablename* is just a placeholder for the actual table name. For obvious reasons, I'm not inclined to give it. At the same time, it's not necessary as the table name is valid. So for now, just say it's [a]. There are no triggers attached to any of the tables in my database.

Comment: *And now I feel like an idiot.*
There was indeed a trigger defined on the table. It's the only table that has one... and the trigger is broken. At least I know how to fix that.  :/